# ssh and sudo su to get interactive terminal without prompt to ask password

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sudo

I want to get an interactive terminal of root via ssh.
The result should be the same as:

```
user1@local$ ssh user2@remote
user2@remote$ sudo su
root@remote# _
```

I already tried:

```
sshpass -p $passwd ssh -t $user@$ip "echo $passwd | sudo -S su"
```

But ssh will terminate immediately after executing this script.
How can I hold the interactive terminal?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Maybe use an `Expect` script, it can end with `interact` to give control to the terminal.

Comment: Use `expect` or `sshpass`.

Comment: Did you try: `sshpass -p "$passwd" ssh -t "$user@$ip" "sshpass -p '$passwd' sudo -S su"` Hint: `sshpass` seems to work for `sudo` prompts as well.

Comment: `sudo su` seems redundant. Generally it is one of the other. Why not just give user2 on remote 2 the ability to `su` without a password by configuring user2 as a member of the `wheel` group and then allowing members of `wheel` to `su` without a password in `/etc/pam.d/su`?